# Need to Populate Component with Nested Data - ReactJS/ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I haven't seen a post to answer this question yet, so forgive me if I overlooked something. I'm trying to populate a table with ONLY the nested array from my data on the page. this.state.data SHOULD contain a subCollection of "masterTicketItems" from the "master ticket" that is being into this React JSX script from the Razor View.

The trouble comes when I'm trying to optimistically update a given table, and ONLY focusing on that, rather than actively posting data. I've been trying look around to understand this ReactJS and ES6 "spread" mapping technique, and I'm not sure if that applies here or something different.

In essence, I'm trying to ONLY map a "LogList" component with a collection contained INSIDE "this.state.data" inside the parent "Ticket" component. I currently have if/else logic to detect if there is nothing in the collection yet, and if not, try to populate it with a SINGLE object from the child component that was "posted" from the LogForm component. However, I can't seem to get the page to render with the single child in the table! Here's the Ticket JSX file snippet for review:

```
class Ticket extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { data: this.props.initialData };
        this.handleLogSubmit = this.handleLogSubmit.bind(this);
    }
    loadLogsFromServer() {
        const xhr = new xmlhttprequest();
        xhr.open('get', this.props.geturl + this.props.id, true);
        xhr.onload = () => {
            const data = json.parse(xhr.responsetext);
            this.setState({ data: data });
        };
        xhr.send();
    }
    handleLogSubmit(log) {
        const logs = this.state.data.apptConfirmItems;
        // Optimistically set an id on the new comment. It will be replaced by an
        // id generated by the server. In a production application you would likely
        // use a more robust system for ID generation.
        if (!logs) {
            log.ticketItemId = 1;
            const newLogs = log;
            let masterItemsAccess = Object.assign({}, this.state.data);
            masterItemsAccess.masterTicketItems = log;
            this.setState((data) => Object.assign({}, data, { masterTicketItems: [log] }));
        }
        else {
            log.ticketItemId = logs.length + 1;
            const newLogs = logs.concat([log]);
            this.setState({ data: newLogs });
        }

        const data = new FormData();
        data.append('ItemType', log.itemType);
        data.append('ItemDescription', log.text);

        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        //xhr.open('post', this.props.submitUrl, true);
        //xhr.onload = () => this.loadLogsFromServer();
        //xhr.send(data);
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        window.setInterval(() => this.loadLogsFromServer(), this.props.pollInterval);
    }
    render() {
        if (!this.state.data.masterTicketItems || this.state.data.masterTicketItems.Count == 0) {
            return (
                <div className="queue">
                    <h1>Affirm Logs</h1>

                    <h2>{this.state.data.summary}</h2>
                    <h5><i>{this.state.data.description}</i></h5>

                    <div><h3>No logs at this time!</h3></div>
                    <LogForm onLogSubmit={this.handleLogSubmit} />
                </div>
            );
        }
        else {
            return (
                <div className="queue">
                    <h1>Affirm Logs</h1>

                    <h2>{this.state.data.summary}</h2>
                    <h5><i>{this.state.data.description}</i></h5>

                    <LogList data={this.state.data.masterTicketItems}/>
                    <LogForm onLogSubmit={this.handleLogSubmit} />
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
}

class LogList extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const logNodes = this.props.data.masterTicketItems.map(log => (
            <Log key={log.ticketItemId}>

                <td>{log.itemType}</td> < td > {log.itemDescription}</td>

            </Log>
        ));
        const logRaw = this.props.data.masterTicketItmes.map(log => (
            <tr>
                <td>{log.itemType}</td><td>{log.itemDescription}</td>
            </tr>
        ));
        return (
            <div className="logList">

                <table id="affirmTable" className="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
                    <tbody>
                        {logNodes}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class LogForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { itemType: 'Test Log', itemDescription: '' };
        this.handleItemTypeChange = this.handleItemTypeChange.bind(this);
        this.handleTextChange = this.handleTextChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }
    handleItemTypeChange(e) {
        this.setState({ itemType: e.target.value });
    }
    handleTextChange(e) {
        this.setState({ itemDescription: e.target.value });
    }
    handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const itemType = this.state.itemType.trim();
        const itemDescription = this.state.itemDescription.trim();
        if (!itemType || !itemDescription) {
            return;
        }
        this.props.onLogSubmit({ ItemType: itemType, ItemDescription: itemDescription });
        this.setState({ itemType: '', text: '' });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <form className="logForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Your name"
                    value={this.state.itemType}
                    onChange={this.handleItemTypeChange}
                />
                <input
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Enter working log here..."
                    value={this.state.itemDescription}
                    onChange={this.handleTextChange}
                />
                <input type="submit" value="Post" />
            </form>
        );
    }
}
```

I purposely left out the child Log component, since I'm confident that when this is addressed that component WILL populate with the table data as expected.

Should I use nested mapping with ES6? Is there a simpler way? I'm trying to understand React state logic a little bit better.